# D3. Within a text string how do I style substrings?

Tags: css, svg, d3.js

For a D3 chart I have various labels. I want to color substrings within a string with different colors. How do I do this?

Specifically I have a string:

```
75: OE 25 KD 35 CP 15
```

I want `OE`, `KD`, and `CP` to each have different colors.

Comment: Niels, why do you feel the need to meddle with the title I give to a question? Seriously annoying, and please don't do it again. By prefacing the questing with D3 this is an aid to visitors to identify what context I am refering to. D3. JS. C++, whatever. Your edit discards that specificity.

Comment: That's what tags are for. The consensus on SO is to **not** include tags in titles. You might want to check the FAQ sections [*"Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190) and [*"How do I write a good title?"*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647) for explanations on this.

Comment: I am not interested in getting into a long winded discussion about minutia. The title is a headline. The web is a scanning medium. Nuff said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put each piece in a `tspan` and style accordingly:

```css
.redText{
  fill: red
}

.blueText{
  fill: steelblue
}

.greenText {
  fill: green
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <text x="20" y="20">
    <tspan>75</tspan>
    <tspan class="redText">OE</tspan>
    <tspan>25</tspan>
    <tspan class="greenText">KD</tspan>
    <tspan>35</tspan>
    <tspan class="blueText">CP</tspan>
    <tspan>15</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```